# "application.extensions.yiiext.renderers.smarty.ESmartyViewRenderer"

Tags: yii, smarty

I have integrated the **smarty template** to my application as specified [here](http://yiiext.github.com/extensions/smarty-renderer/index.html)

But I am getting the above error.

[image]

I have tried all the possible ways to paste the **Yii Smarty parser**

**Config**

```
'viewRenderer'=>array(
      'class'=>'application.ext.ESmartyViewRenderer',
        'fileExtension' => '.tpl',
        //'pluginsDir' => 'application.smartyPlugins',
        //'configDir' => 'application.smartyConfig',
        //'prefilters' => array(array('MyClass','filterMethod')),
        //'postfilters' => array(),
        //'config'=>array(
        //    'force_compile' => YII_DEBUG,
        //   ... any Smarty object parameter
        //)
    ),
```

My pleasure to see if any one suggest other(best) template engine..

**EDIT**

exact error message

```
Alias "application.extensions.yiiext.renderers.smarty.ESmartyViewRenderer" is invalid. Make sure it points to an existing PHP file and the file is readable.
```

Comment: your error is not clear (incomplete), what exactly is it?

Comment: have your tried with just `ext.ESmartyViewRenderer` ?

Comment: please show your config file

Comment: i meant only `ext.ESmartyViewRenderer` not `application.ext.ESmartyViewRenderer` anyway you have a lot of other files, folders, it should be only ESmartyViewRenderer and plugins directory

Comment: @bool.dev: Yes working..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try with:

```
'class'=>'ext.ESmartyViewRenderer', // or application.extensions.ESmartyViewRenderer should also work
```

The *protected/extensions* directory is already aliased as `ext`.

Answer (score 3):

```
Alias "application.extensions.yiiext.renderers.smarty.ESmartyViewRenderer" is invalid. Make sure it points to an existing PHP file and the file is readable.
```

use the right path in the above case.

```
application.extensions.ESmartyViewRenderer
```

If you extract your file inside a new folder *protected/extensions/smarty* instead of *protected/extensions*
 then use

```
application.extensions.smarty.ESmartyViewRenderer
```

Comment: actually this is also right, hemc also shows how to access extension incase there's another folder within which the extension file is located. so plus one