# How to resize an image in YII?

Tags: php, yii

When I try to load and resize an image:

```
$image = Yii::app()->image->load($path);
$image->resize(400, 100);
```

I get this error

```
Property "CWebApplication.image" is not defined.
```

I've tried in the config file to put this:

```
'image'=>array(
          'class'=>'application.extensions.image.CImageComponent',
            // GD or ImageMagick
            'driver'=>'GD',
            // ImageMagick setup path
            'params'=>array('directory'=>'/opt/local/bin'),
        ),
```

anyway I'am getting an error, how to resize an image in yii any ideas?, is there any native class to work with images?

Answer (score 3):

When configuring application components put them in `components` config section, it seems that you put image component in wrong place.

This should work:

```
return [
    // ....
    'components' => [
        'image' => [
            'class' => 'application.extensions.image.CImageComponent',
            // GD or ImageMagick
            'driver' => 'GD',
            // ImageMagick setup path
            'params' => ['directory' => '/opt/local/bin'],
        ],
    ]
];
```

Comment: Alias "application.extensions.image.CImageComponent" is invalid. Make sure it points to an existing PHP file and the file is readable. - now I get this... :(

Comment: Thats common mistake, see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13417164/application-extensions-yiiext-renderers-smarty-esmartyviewrenderer

Comment: never user `[]` to declare array()

Comment: @user1954544 please explain your claim (which is wrong). It's new syntax introduced in php 5.4 and it's perfectly fine.

Comment: because it's introduced SINCE 5.4, it's enough not to use this feature. it's like `<?= ... ?>` everybody know - noone use, think about ;)

Comment: Using `[]` is way more clean than cluttering code with `array` words. Honestly, after years of writing this bloody `array` word finally php guys decided to add syntax recognized in most languages, so we can use it, so use it. Also note that php 5.3 is no longer supported, 5 days ago was last release.

Answer (score 1):

I think its too late response. But it will help others. I have a got into a similar problem. I fixed it by the following method.

From your question i understand that you are using an extension called ["image"](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/image/) in yii. In the page of the extension itself they given a description called ["usage"](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/image/#hh4). I followed that to fix.

I have added some note in the usage documentation and added below which may lead to that issue.

The following code is the component registration in the config file(config/main.php):

```
'import'=>array(
    ...
    'application.helpers.*',
    ...
),
```

May be you may done mistake in this following part. you need to register the "image" component inside the components section in the config/main.php file.

```
'components'=>array(
       'image'=>array(
          'class'=>'application.extensions.image.CImageComponent',
            // GD or ImageMagick
            'driver'=>'GD',
            // ImageMagick setup path
            'params'=>array('directory'=>'/opt/local/bin'),
        ),...
)
```

See the following code example:

```
$image = Yii::app()->image->load('images/test.jpg');
$image->resize(400, 100)->rotate(-45)->quality(75)->sharpen(20);
$image->save(); // or $image->save('images/small.jpg');//You missed this line
```

(or) you can also use like below without registering the image component in the config/main.php file.

```
Yii::import('application.extensions.image.Image');
$image = new Image('images/test.jpg');
$image->resize(400, 100)->rotate(-45)->quality(75)->sharpen(20);
$image->render();
```

Answer (score 0):

You must add the ImageMagick setup path in config file "main.php"

here the sample for windows

```
'image'=>array(
        'class'=>'application.extensions.image.CImageComponent',
        // GD or ImageMagick
        'driver'=>'GD',
        // ImageMagick setup path
        'params'=>array('directory'=>'D:/Program Files/ImageMagick-6.4.8-Q16'),
    ),
```

for linux

```
'image'=>array(
        'class'=>'application.extensions.image.CImageComponent',
        // GD or ImageMagick
        'driver'=>'GD',
        // ImageMagick setup path
        'params' => array('directory' => '/usr/bin'),
    ),
```

and then you can resize the image like this

```
$image = Yii::app()->image->load('images/test.jpg');
$image->resize(400, 100)->rotate(-45)->quality(75)->sharpen(20);
$image->save(); // or $image->save('images/small.jpg');
```

use the flowing extension 
[image extension](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/image/)